# Disable options to move/reorder panels in WP Classic Editor

Tags: wordpress, editor

I have a client that keeps dragging the editor panels out of order (sometimes while also collapsing them) and even if I keep rearranging them for her, she keeps complaining that "Wordpress is broken". She just doesn't get how to work with them while editing products.

[image]

I have searched the internet far and wide and saw no topics on this.

I want to either:

- find a solution (or plugin) to PIN the panels in place so they cannot be moved/reordered
- DISABLE the panel controls altogether (move arrow, drag area, collapse arrow) in a way that cannot be overwritten by WP updates

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: In the meantime, ChatGPT v4 gave the following answer. I need to test this but it might break functionality in other areas in WP Admin. Still needs some human oversight/improvement:

functions.php:

function disable_drag_and_drop() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        echo '<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(document).on("mousedown", ".postbox .hndle", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'disable_drag_and_drop');

Comment: Have you tested it? How did it work out? Did you have to change the code any?